# How do I modify the request body so that I can send a new object to a controller internally?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

Ok, I apologize for the subject. I really didn't know how else to ask.

We have a custom dispatcher in our Web Api that allows us to select different controllers based on a version number embedded in the header. The problem that we're facing is that exceptions that are thrown in this class are being silently handled by the framework. Rather, we can catch the exception and attempt to handle it but since there's no apparent way to modify the default response at this level, all of our handling gets ignored.

The workaround that we're currently pursuing is basically to leverage the fact that we're in the middle of selecting a controller when this exception is thrown, so we want to catch that exception and send it a controller to have that rethrow so that it can be caught by our error filters. Sounds klugy, but that's what we're working with. The problem that I'm dealing with right now, I've gotten it to select the ExceptionController that I've created that rethrows, however I'm not sure how to send the exception object to this controller. Here's an example of the catch block:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    var routeValues = request.GetRouteData().Values;
    routeValues["controller"] = "Exception";
    routeValues["action"] = "Exception";
    controllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(_config, "exceptionController", typeof(ExceptionController));

}
return controllerDescriptor;
```

The controller method has the following signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Exception(Exception ex)
```

My first instinct is to modify the request body, which is of the the type HttpRequestMessage but I can't quite figure out how to do that. I should just be able to modify that request before the ExceptionController is called.

So I guess the question is, how do I modify the request object to give it the exception object, or is there another way to go about this?

TIA